# CRM 2013 Plugins can some one explain to me, what is the difference In "Message,Pipepline Stage, Pre Image Alias, post ImageAlias, paramters

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Can some one please explain to me, what is the difference in CRM 2013 plugins between:

-"Message" (Assign, Create, Delete, Grant Access, ModifiyAccess, retrieve, RetriveMuliple, RetrievePrincipalAccess, RetriveSharedPricipalAndAccess, Revoke Access, SetState, SetstateDynamicEnitity and update)

-Pipeline Stage (pre-Validation, Pre- Operation and Post Operation)

-Pre Image Alias (parameters)

-post ImageAlias ( parameters) please in details..

I am new to CRM and trying to create a Plugin, but I was googling in net to know the difference between them, but there was not enough information
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is lot of information on MSDN. Just need to google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "message" is the actionable event that is taking place.  On Create, a record is being inserted into CRM.  For retrieve, a single record is being returned.  Etc.

**Pipeline Stage** - Specifies when you want the plug-in to execute: before (Pre) or after (Post) the core operation that processes the message. For more information, see [Event execution pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx).

**Pre Image Alias** - A pre-image is a snapshot of the entity’s attributes before the core operation.

**Post Image Alias** - A post-image is a snapshot of the entity’s attribute after the core operation.

If you are getting started, I'd suggest looking into the SDK.  There are samples to get you started and help to explain a lot of this.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

Answer (score 0):

For your Question. Let's take an example on Creation of Entity record the field value should be Updated for that case "Create" is the Message in Plugin Registration Tool and Service is the Update. likewise there are More number of Messages According to Message Inputparameter will change accordingly. for yourself let's start from Crud operations you will Understood easily.

Coming to Pipeline stages:there are three

1. Pre-Validation(execute outside of the db transactions)
2. Pre- Operation(execute within the db transactions)
3. Post Operation(execute within the db transactions)

Take one plugin apply all above operations then you will understood.

Coming to Pre image and Post image:

Pre image will work on while update it will fetch data from sql db.
Post image will work on both create and update same as post fetch data from sql db.

---